# how to use exist certificate to sign an apk with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

generate apk with the command

```
# expo build:android
```

and upload to google play console.

But it fails and says; `You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate`

then what I did go to `App Signing` section and downloaded `deloyment.cert` file,

now I wonder how I can tell expo to use this file to sign and build apk file?

expo cli version 3.22.3
The hashes in keystore of `# expo credentials:manager` output diffirent from what it looks in store, how can I generate new keystore file to update this info?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can run `expo credentials:manager` in your project directory to manage the signing credentials for your project. read more about app signing on android with expo managed projects at https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-signing/#android

Comment: thanks for answer, but think need little more help, updated the post

Comment: there are deployment and upload certs on google play. you previously signed your binary using a certain upload keystore, now you're signing it using a different one. you need to find the one you used before and upload it to expo using `expo credentials:manager`. if you don't have access to that keystore anymore, you can ask google to reset it for you